# Modules over a PID with tensor relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, principal-ideal-domains

I am trying to work through the following problem:

Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain and let $K$ be the field of fractions of $R$. Let $M$ and $N$ be finitely generated $R$-modules. Let $Hom_R (M,N)$ be the set of $R$-module homomorphisms $\phi$ from $M$ to $N$. Show that

$$Hom_R (M, N) \otimes_R K \cong Hom_K (M \otimes_R K, N \otimes_R K)$$

My approach was to try to think of a trivial mapping between the two and then prove it is an isomorphism: $\psi_m (\phi \otimes k) = \phi(m) \otimes k$ but am not sure how to leverage the fact that both modules are finitely generated. Do I instead need to show we can map bases to bases?

Comment: Your idea seems like a good one; though I'd think the map would have to be described something more like $\varphi \otimes k \mapsto (m \otimes k' \mapsto \varphi(m) \otimes k k')$.  My guess is that the finitely generated condition would probably come into play while you're trying to show it's surjective.

Comment: While you're working on the problem, it might be helpful to know that $M \otimes_R K$ is isomorphic to the module of fractions $\frac{m}{a}$ with $m\in M, a\in R\setminus\{0\}$ modulo equivalence $\frac{m}{a} = \frac{m'}{a'}$ if and only if $a' m = a m'$, etc.